# Can we solve for $c$ in the equation $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-jc\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $N\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq N-1$ be fixed numbers, and $c>0$ be unknown. Suppose we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-jc\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $j:=\sqrt{-1}$. Equivalently, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \cos\left(c\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \sin\left(c\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Is it possible to simplify and solve the above equations to arrive at a closed form expression for $c$ in terms of $k$ and $N$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $j:=\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes. That is right. Thanks for the comment. I'll add that in the question.

Comment: Can you do the case $N=1$?  How about $N=2$?

Answer (score 2):

Up to $N=4$ it can be solved symbolically.  But Maple finds no symbolic solution for $N=5$.  When $N=5,k=0$ we get
$$
Q_{5,0}(c) := 
1+{{\rm e}^{-jc\sin \left( 2/5\,\pi  \right) }}+{{\rm e}^{-jc\sin
 \left( \pi /5 \right) }}+{{\rm e}^{jc\sin \left( \pi /5 \right) }}+{
{\rm e}^{jc\sin \left( 2/5\,\pi  \right) }}
$$
By its symmetry, the imaginary part is always zero.  $Q_{5,0}$ is almost periodic, but not periodic.  $Q_{5,0}(c)=0$ has infinitely many solutions for $c$.
[image: graph]